# CSS @font-face not working

Tags: css

i was trying to use @font-face first time but it does not works can anybody help me to solve this problem 
Why this script is not working

```
<style>
    @font-face{ 
        font-family: myfont;
        src: url('entypo.eot');
        src: url('entypo.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
             url('entypo.woff') format('woff'),
             url('entypo.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('entypo.svg#helvetica') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    div {
        font-family: myfont;
    }
</style>

 </head>
 <body>
     <div>
          sdfdfdsfsdf
     </div>
```

Comment: Where does the font come from? How did you produce the different formats? Are you sure you uploaded the files? Where? Which browser(s) did you test things on? What does “is not working” mean?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'SegoeUI';
    src: url('Fonts/segoeui.eot');
    src: url('Fonts/segoeui.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/segoeui.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: 'SegoeLight';
    src: url('Fonts/segoeuil.eot');
    src: url('Fonts/segoeuil.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/segoeuil.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your font is not an English font, right? anyway. i faced this problem a lot because i use Persian fonts and sometimes they don't work! what i do is re-convert them into different font formats with different softwares like online font converter. and sometimes my fonts work in IE, Firefox but not chrome! and then i re-convert them and everything change to normal! so re-converting them may solve your problem.
PS: some cool sites for doing such a thing:
[font face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)
[font 2 web](http://www.font2web.com)

Comment: yes it is not English font. its a free icon font which i download from web

Comment: @shinosn so i think my answer is yours

Answer (score 0):

Add `'` to myfont, and change `helvetica` to `myfont` like this:

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('entypo.eot');
    src: url('entypo.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('entypo.woff') format('woff'),
         url('entypo.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('entypo.svg#myfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

div {
    font-family: 'myfont';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your font should be placed relevant to the CSS, if it is in separate folder use relevant path

for example

```
// Directory Structure
images
css
fonts
-index.html
```

if your fonts are in a folder and CSS in other folder use the following css

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('../fonts/entypo.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/entypo.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('../fonts/entypo.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/entypo.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/entypo.svg#myfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```